# How can i extend a class with many pararms in javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

```
class A{
 constructor(p1,p2,p3){
    this.p1=p1;
    this.p2=p2;
    this.p3=p3;
 }
}
class B extends A{
 constructor(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5){
    super(p1,p2,p3);
    this.p4=p4;
    this.p5=p5;
 }
}
```

i have learned to use this form,but still don't know how to extend Class A with many pararms by a read-able way

```
class A{
 constructor(obj){
    this.p1=obj.p1;
    this.p2=obj.p2;
    this.p3=obj.p3;
 }
}
```

If my code is not the bestway to that,please tell me how to do that instand,thanks!

**More question**

@T.J. Crowder
 I tried to use *option object* to extend class A but it doesn't work,what did i miss?

```
class A{
 constructor(opt){
  this.p1=opt.p1;
  this.p2=opt.p2;
  this.p3=opt.p3;
 }
}
class B extends A{
 constructor(opt){
  super(opt.p1,opt.p2,opt.p3);
  this.p4=opt.p4;
  this.p5=opt.p5;
 }
}
var instant=new B({p1:1,p2:2,p3:3,p4:4,p5:5});
console.log('p1:'+instant.p1);
console.log('p2:'+instant.p2);
console.log('p5:'+instant.p5);
```

The output is p1:undefind;p2:undefind;p5:5

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this, but I'm not finding it... :-|

Comment: for additional description，my purpose is to use an object like {p1:'1',p2:'2',...,p5:'5'} as  an argument to new an object by class B

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can't find good dupes for using spread to call a function. You're right, we *should* have some, but I'm mostly finding object spread, array copying and the like.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is dupetarget?
I did a google, was able to understand that this is some trivial syntax problem.
Hence a dupetarget?

Comment: @UtsavPatel - A "dupetarget" is a question that's already on the site whose answers answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your child class `B` adds the properties it needs at the end, and the first ones will always be for `A`, then you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that every function receives:

```js
class A{
 constructor(p1,p2,p3){
    this.p1=p1;
    this.p2=p2;
    this.p3=p3;
 }
}
class B extends A{
 constructor(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5){
    super(...arguments);
//        ^^^ spread the arguments to call the super constructor
    this.p4=p4;
    this.p5=p5
 }
}

const instance = new B("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");

console.log("instance.p1:", instance.p1);
console.log("instance.p2:", instance.p2);
console.log("instance.p3:", instance.p3);
console.log("instance.p4:", instance.p4);
console.log("instance.p5:", instance.p5);
```

This will effectively call `super(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)`, however since the constructor for `A` only cares about the first three parameters, it will ignore the rest.

Comment: This might be the easiest solution for me to understand,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the point where you think a function or constructor has too many parameters and it'll be hard to keep them straight, a common approach is to use an *options object*, or perhaps one or two parameters and an optional options object, instead.

For instance:

```
constructor(options) {
    super(options.p1, options.p2, options.p3);
    // ...use options.p4 and options.p5 here...
}
```

You call that passing in an object:

```
new B({p1: "x", p2: "y", /*...*/});
```

You can use destructuring in the parameter list if you like, to get individual locals for the properties of the options object:

```
constructor({p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}) {
    super(p1, p2, p3);
    // ...use p4 and p5 here...
}
```

You might even update `A` so that accepts an options object rather than discrete parameters as well. For instance:

```
class A {
    constructor({p1, p2, p3}) {
        // ...use p1, p2, and p3 here...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor({p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}) {
        super({p1, p2, p3});
        // ...use p4 and p5 here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your `obj` with `this` in the constructor by doing something like this

```
constructor (obj) {
  Object.assign(this, obj);
  console.log(this.p1, this.p2);
}
```

Comment: But now you're not in control over *what* fields that object has. Maybe the consumer provided `p1` maybe they didn't. So, maybe you now have that property, maybe not. This can also add properties you never actually wanted in the first place, like adding a `toString` for example.